# UITableView like Facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In the current version of Facebook app there's a cell at the top of the timeline view called "News Feed". It's the post filter feature. If you tap it, new cells at the bottom of that cell slides down and became visible. It's a pleasurable effect. Did you know how to implement something alike? In your opinion all happens inside the same UITableViewCell or what?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achievable using [insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38)

Bear in mind that your data source for the table needs to accommodate for the inserted rows, and so does your `numberOfRowsInSection` method as well.

I think the appropriate animation effect to use here is `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` so that the cells look like they're inserting from top to bottom.

In your example, once the user taps on the news feed cell, you would probably do:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` method would return your original value + 3.

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should have code to build the news cells which have just been added.

Comment: thanks. But so it's s `UITableView` inside the main `UITableView`?

Comment: No it's one of the instance methods of a UITableView. It uses your UITableViewDataSource methods to render the new cells that you add. You will be calling this method on the tableview that you want to add your rows to.

Comment: Sid, sorry for late reply. So if it's the same main `UITableView`, the rows are custom `UITableViewCell` without margins? It seems that the new rows are in the same cell as the first one `"News Feed"`, it isn't?

Comment: Fred, there's multiple ways to achieve the same effect in such a case. It's possible to customize the margins of a cell. Also, you can set the UITableView's separatorColor property to be `[UIColor clearColor]` for individual cells so you can make it look like some cells have borders while others don't, so they look like part of the same cell.